# Get value from package.json or bower.json in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, package, bower

Is it possible to get some metadata from package.json or from bower.json in angularjs ?

For example, I have a property:
"version": 1.0.0

and in the app, I'd like to use this value.

I'm using 1.4.8

Comment: How it corresponds to my question?

Comment: You can get json file this method and get value
$http.get("package.json") .then(function(response) { response.version});

Comment: Depending on the bundler and es6 availability, `import * as config from "package.json"` would work. Otherwise, the standard `var config = require("package.json");`. Then, just grab it from the imported object. `config.version`